# Image Width 100% of Page

Tags: html, image, css

I have a simple code to insert into a website to post image-links.
However, even though it's set at `width: 100%` It's affected by the parent div. The image only maximises to the parent div.

```
<center><a href="link.html">
<img style="width: 100%;" src="img.jpg"/>
</a></center>
```

The parent div constrains content so it doesn't touch the edge of the page.

How can I make the image 100% of the page, not the parent div?

Comment: Why just dont move the element upper? Or instead of using img element, use [image-background CSS property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

Comment: You can set it to `width: 100vw` and then compensate manually but that's hacky at best. If you want to image to be outside of the parent set it outside the parent. There might be other ways to do this. Can you create an example?

Comment: I've just decided to use `width: 100vw` and compensated with `margin-left` but that works fine for mobile.
For desktop, it veers off to the left. It'll do for now.

Comment: The parent `div` must have `position: relative` being set, why don't you try `position:fixed` for the `img` to be anchored to the viewport instead?

Comment: Move the image out of the div into one that's 100% of the page width.

Comment: **center** is not a valid HTML5 tag and, anyway, it's really useless in this case.

Comment: As I didn't get any response I deleted my answer.